# MATLAB Data Cursor won't click on every point of plot (R2018b)

Tags: matlab, grid, cursor

I need to get the plot values in between those two points, but when I click with the data cursor in between, the label appears either left or right, as if the cursor only picks up points on a fixed grid.

[image]

Is there a way to increase this precision so I can click and get the values in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution:

In the code, this needs to be set after the plot:

```
dcmObj = datacursormode;
set(dcmObj,'SnapToDataVertex','off')
```